# Liferay DocumentAndMedia hook with CMIS

Tags: java, liferay, hook, cmis

I made a hook from DocumentAndMedia. In portal.properties i wrote com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction=com.mycompany.acciones.Test so when i see the file entry view i can get the fileentry. I want to cast FileEntry to org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl document from the fileEntry.getModel() to get some extra properties but an exception is throw.

Test Action Class

```
package com.mycompany.acciones;

import javax.portlet.*;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.*;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.*;

public class Test extends BaseStrutsPortletAction{

    public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,PortletConfig portletConfig,RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {

        String ret = originalStrutsPortletAction.render(null, portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
        renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_DECORATE, Boolean.TRUE);

        FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry)renderRequest.getAttribute("DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_FILE_ENTRY"); 

        // Exception is throws here
        DocumentImpl doc = (DocumentImpl)fileEntry.getModel();      

        String propertyName = doc.getProperties().get(0).getDisplayName();
        String propertyvalue = doc.getProperties().get(0).getValue();

        String propertyName2 = doc.getProperties().get(1).getDisplayName();
        String propertyvalue2 = doc.getProperties().get(1).getValue();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
17:33:52,796 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-398][render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl
    at com.mycompany.acciones.Test.render(Test.java:31)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletActionAdapter.render(PortletActionAdapter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletAction.execute(PortletAction.java:111)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PortletRequestProcessor.java:441)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:224)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.include(StrutsPortlet.java:274)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.doView(StrutsPortlet.java:153)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:218)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:548)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:607)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1207)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class can't be typecasted to another class that it legitimately should (even to itself) you definitely have the incriminating class or its superclass twice on the classpath. Check your classpath for duplicates, resolve it. It might be a library that is in tomcat's global classpath (`tomcat/lib`, or for Liferay also `tomcat/lib/ext`) or your webapplication (there in its `WEB-INF/lib` or `WEB-INF/classes`). Or a combination of all of them (as it's multiple implementations of a class with the same name.

Get rid of the superfluous ones, restart, try again.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. It works for me! I had to move the apache chemistry libs (webapps/root/web-inf/lib) to tomcat/lib/ext and delete them from myhook/web-inf/lib

Answer (score 0):

package test;

```
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsPortletAction;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.StrutsPortletAction;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry;

public class EditFileEntryAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {

     public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

            originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,PortletConfig portletConfig,RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {

            String ret = originalStrutsPortletAction.render(null, portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
            renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_DECORATE, Boolean.TRUE);

            FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry)renderRequest.getAttribute("DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_FILE_ENTRY"); 

            // Exception is throws here
            DLFileEntry doc = (DLFileEntry)fileEntry.getModel();      


            return ret;
        }
}
```

This worked for me, but the cast is DLFileEntry, not DocumentImpl.

Why do you need org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl and how do you know, that getModel() returns with this type of object?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use DocumentImpl because I'm using cmis implementation on my liferay. I need some extra attributes from this object that DLFileEntry hasn't. The method fileEntry.getModel() returns an Object but the CmisFileEntry.getModel() return a cmis document